# How to change chunk.js name in angular 4 lazy loading

Tags: angular, webpack, lazy-loading

I implemented lazy loading module in angular 4. it work well.
and when I navigate to the new page, it will load extra js file like: 
0.chunk.js, 1.chunk.js.

my question is: how to change that chunk name?
ex:
1.chunk.js => about.js
0.chunk.js => user.js

Comment: Do you use `require.ensure` or `import`? Please give us sample of this code.

Comment: Hi @Everettss, you can go to this github [repo](https://github.com/leepheng/angular-lazyload-basic) for source code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far the only way I know how to name lazy loaded chunks is by using a webpack config outside of Angular CLI with the angular-router-loader package:

https://github.com/brandonroberts/angular-router-loader/blob/master/docs/options.md#lazy-loading-options

Here's an example of the loader in a webpack.config.js file

```
{
    test: /\.ts$/,
    loaders: [
      {
          loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
          options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json')
      }
      },  
      'angular-router-loader',
      'angular2-template-loader'
    ]
}
```

Then the routing paths should by configured like so:

```
{
  path: 'lazy',
  loadChildren './lazy.module#LazyModule?chunkName=MyChunk'
}
```

I've been waiting for a while for this feature to get added to the angular cli. Here's the issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5171

Comment: For those just skimming, the answer for me was the '?chunkName=MyChunk' on the lazy loaded routes.

Answer (score 3):

Update @angular/cli to [1.3.0-beta](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases). It automatically provides name for your lazy chunks as `your-lazy-loading.module.chunk.js`. All I need to do is `npm install -g @angular/cli@1.3.0-beta.1` and update `package.json` as

```
devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.3.0-beta.1", 
...
}
```

Finally, run `npm install`. So, you are good to go!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using Webpack for build Angular.

in webpack.config we a config attribute "output".

Change to (ex) :

```
const DistDirectory = path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist');

...,
output: {
   path: DistDirectory,
   filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js'
}
```

In this case, our results will be like this: 
0.89872d7bedaacc90c95a.bundle.js

Hope it helpful.

P/s: You also have this config in angular-cli I think